# Using NDSolve for three variables as function of time

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to be able to plot z, and r.
Should I be using DSolve, NDSolve or something else?
I've tried to clear it up a bit

Thanks,

Will

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

(*Constants*)
rho = 1000;
g = 9.81;
Patm = 100000;
gma = 0.0728;
mu = 0.0001;
rs = 287;
T = 293.15;
Psat = 2399;

(*Variables*)
r0 = 25*(10^-6)

(*equations*)
Pl = rho*g*z[t] + Patm;

eqn1 = Pb[t] == rho*g*z[t] + Patm + (2*gma)/r[t]

eqn2 = r[t] == (((1 + (Psat/Pb[t]))*(rho*g*z[t] + Patm)*r0^3)/Pb[t])^(1/3)

eqn3 = z'[t] == -(2/9)*(1/mu)*(r[t]^2)*(Pl - Pb[t]/(rs*T))


eqn = {eqn1 && eqn2 &&  eqn3 , r[0] == 0.000025 && z[0] == 1 }


sol = NDSolve[eqn, {r[t], Pb[t], z[t]}, t, {Z[t], 1, 0}]
```

Comment: I am really confused looking at the above code. You have only one differential equation there. `dz/dt` so why are you trying to solve for 3? You are also defining `Pb[t]` in terms of `r[t]` and also defining `r[t]` as function of `Pb[t]` which looks like a circle to me.

Comment: I would like to solve for that one differential equation. But within that I need to solve again for Pb and r? How would i do that?

Comment: Pl in eqn3 is undefined

Comment: Yes I have defined Pl now. Thanks. Would it help if i describe the physical system?

Comment: First, I think this is the call you intend: `sol = NDSolve[eqn, {r[t], Pb[t], z[t]}, {t, 1, 0}]`.  If not, please explain.  Second, if that is the call, then `Solve[#, Pb[0]] & /@ ({eqn1, eqn2} /. {t -> 0} /. {z[0] -> 1, r[0] -> 0.000025})` shows that your initial conditions are inconsistent.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/201125?p_p_auth=zWCu60eQ

Answer (score 1):

Once the trivial things are fixed -- I borrowed the definition of `Pl` from the Wolfram Community posting -- the problem is that `NDSolve` has trouble setting up the initial conditions from `r[0] == 0.000025`, in particular, I suppose for `Pb[0]`.  The solution is to specify both `r[0]` and `Pb[0]`.

### OP's setup

I converted each parameter setting to a `Rule`, so I could play with them more easily.

```
(*equations*)
Pl = rho*g*z[t] + Patm;
eqn1 = Pb[t] == rho*g*z[t] + Patm + (2*gma)/r[t];
eqn2 = r[t] == (((1 + (Psat/Pb[t]))*(rho*g*z[t] + Patm)*r0^3)/Pb[t])^(1/3);
eqn3 = z'[t] == -(2/9)*(1/mu)*(r[t]^2)*(Pl - Pb[t]/(rs*T));

eqn = {eqn1 && eqn2 && eqn3, z[0] == 1};

params12 = Union@Cases[{eqn1, eqn2}, _Symbol, Infinity] /. t -> Sequence[];
params = Union@Cases[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}, _Symbol, Infinity] /. t -> Sequence[];

paramSettings = Hold[
     rho = 1000;
     g = 9.81;
     Patm = 100000;
     gma = 0.0728;
     mu = 0.0001;
     rs = 287;
     T = 293.15;
     Psat = 2399;
     r0 = 25*(10^-6)] /. Set -> Rule /. CompoundExpression -> List // 
  ReleaseHold

(*
   {rho -> 1000, g -> 9.81, Patm -> 100000, gma -> 0.0728, mu -> 0.0001, 
    rs -> 287, T -> 293.15, Psat -> 2399, r0 -> 1/40000}
*)
```

### Solving the OP's setup

We solve the algebraic constraints at `t -> 0` for the initial values of `r[0]` and `Pb[0]`.  The warning makes me worry about the sensitivity of the results to the uncertainty of the parameter settings.  The warning does not suggest that, but converting to exact coefficients could hide it.

```
icsOP = Equal @@@ 
  First@NSolve[{eqn1, eqn2} /. t -> 0 /. {z[0] -> 1} /. paramSettings,
    {r[0], Pb[0]}, Reals]
```

> NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

```
(*
   {r[0] == 0.0000247373, Pb[0] == 115696.}
*)
```

Using both equations in `icsOP` helps `NDSolve` initialize the algebraic constraints.  We can also see that `r[0] == 0.000025` is a little off, which is why `NDSolve` won't solve the system with the original setup.  It still seems to have trouble if I give it just the one for `r[0]`.

```
solOP = First @ NDSolve[{eqn, icsOP} /. paramSettings, {r[t], Pb[t], z[t]}, {t, 1, 0}]
(*
   {r[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][t],
    Pb[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][t],
    z[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][t]}
*)
```

Below we see that `NSolve` does not find a solution for `Pb[0]` even if we give the solution for `r[0]` it found above, although it will if we specify the domain `Reals`.

```
NSolve[{eqn1, eqn2} /. t -> 0 /. 
    r[0] -> 0.000024737308346837383` /. {z[0] -> 1} /. paramSettings, 
 Pb[0]]
(* 
  {}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. This is to model bubbles in a column of water. I now just need to account for diffusivity. THANKS AGAIN!